# How to display the first few characters of a string in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I just started learning Python but I'm sort of stuck right now.

I have `hash.txt` file containing thousands of malware hashes in MD5, Sha1 and Sha5 respectively separated by delimiters in each line. Below are 2 examples lines I extracted from the .txt file.

> 416d76b8811b0ddae2fdad8f4721ddbe|d4f656ee006e248f2f3a8a93a8aec5868788b927|12a5f648928f8e0b5376d2cc07de8e4cbf9f7ccbadb97d898373f85f0a75c47f
> 56a99a4205a4d6cab2dcae414a5670fd|612aeeeaa8aa432a7b96202847169ecae56b07ee|d17de7ca4c8f24ff49314f0f342dbe9243b10e9f3558c6193e2fd6bccb1be6d2

My intention is to display the first 32 characters (MD5 hash) so the output will look something like this:

> 416d76b8811b0ddae2fdad8f4721ddbe 56a99a4205a4d6cab2dcae414a5670fd

Any ideas?

Comment: Read this [brief Introduction to Python](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html), and scroll about halfway down. "String slicing" is what you want.

Comment: `the_string[:32]`

Comment: String slicing and how to open files if you haven't read that already

Comment: You're probably also going to be interested in the `.split()` and `.strip()` methods of strings.  For example, `md5, sha1, sha5 = line.strip().split("|")` does pretty much what you'd guess it would.

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys I finally got it to work. I tried each and every methods and it seems like TankorSmash's works the most convenient for me. I appreciate each and everyone's help!

Answer (score 210, accepted):

You can 'slice' a `string` very easily, just like you'd pull items from a `list`:

```
a_string = 'This is a string'
```

To get the first 4 letters:

```
first_four_letters = a_string[:4]
>>> 'This'
```

Or the last 5:

```
last_five_letters = a_string[-5:]
>>> 'string'
```

So applying that logic to your problem:

```
the_string = '416d76b8811b0ddae2fdad8f4721ddbe|d4f656ee006e248f2f3a8a93a8aec5868788b927|12a5f648928f8e0b5376d2cc07de8e4cbf9f7ccbadb97d898373f85f0a75c47f '
first_32_chars = the_string[:32]
>>> 416d76b8811b0ddae2fdad8f4721ddbe
```

Comment: @César: it is generally better (and faster) to show the fact that you only need the first part of the splited string with `the_string.split('|', 1)[0]`.

Answer (score 18):

Since there is a delimiter, you should use that instead of worrying about how long the md5 is.

```
>>> s = "416d76b8811b0ddae2fdad8f4721ddbe|d4f656ee006e248f2f3a8a93a8aec5868788b927|12a5f648928f8e0b5376d2cc07de8e4cbf9f7ccbadb97d898373f85f0a75c47f"
>>> md5sum, delim, rest = s.partition('|')
>>> md5sum
'416d76b8811b0ddae2fdad8f4721ddbe'
```

Alternatively

```
>>> md5sum, sha1sum, sha5sum = s.split('|')
>>> md5sum
'416d76b8811b0ddae2fdad8f4721ddbe'
>>> sha1sum
'd4f656ee006e248f2f3a8a93a8aec5868788b927'
>>> sha5sum
'12a5f648928f8e0b5376d2cc07de8e4cbf9f7ccbadb97d898373f85f0a75c47f'
```

Comment: +1 for considering the delimiter stuff for variable length hash :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you want first 2 letters and last 2 letters of a string then you can use the following code:
`name = "India"
name[0:2]="In"
names[-2:]="ia"`