# Modify string line by line in Python

Tags: python, string, loops

I'm new to Python, I apologize if the question is simple. I have a string called decShow with this informartion:

```
 00:00:00,000 -> 94 FB
 00:00:00,100 -> 94 FA
 00:00:00,200 -> 94 F9
 00:00:00,300 -> 94 F8
 00:00:00,400 -> 94 F7
 00:00:00,500 -> 94 F6
 00:00:00,600 -> 94 F5
 00:00:00,700 -> 94 F4
 00:00:00,800 -> 94 F3
 00:00:00,900 -> 94 F2
 00:00:01,000 -> 94 F1
 00:00:01,100 -> 94 20

HH:MM:SS,sss -> Hex Code
```

I want to modify that string line by line, creating another string like this

```
00000000: Hex Code
```

where the zeros are a HEX value resulting from the conversion of each line minutes, seconds and miliseconds to miliseconds in hexadecimal. Maths are not the problem, the problem is the loop. After trying with a `for line in decShow` I'm not having the results I expected.

How can I efficiently do that?

EDIT: To clarify.

I have this in a string:

```
 00:00:00,000 -> 94 FB
 00:00:00,100 -> 94 FA
 00:00:00,200 -> 94 F9
 00:00:00,300 -> 94 F8
```

I want to transform it into this:

```
00000000: 94 FB
00000064: 94 FA
000000C8: 94 F9
0000012C: 94 F8
```

I tried a loop under `for line in decShow` but it seems it works just for `.readlines()`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], it's unclear what you've tried, what the results were or how they differed from what you expected.

Comment: Please paste your `hex` conversion code as well

Comment: I just added more info. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split string using a newline delimiter with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22042948/split-string-using-a-newline-delimiter-with-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> tup_lst = [re.split(r' -> |,', l.strip()) for l in decShow.splitlines()]
>>> new_data = '\n'.join([a.replace(':', '')+'%03X: ' % int(b)+c for a,b,c in tup_lst])
>>> print (new_data)
```

**Output**

```
000000000: 94 FB
000000064: 94 FA
0000000C8: 94 F9
00000012C: 94 F8
000000190: 94 F7
0000001F4: 94 F6
000000258: 94 F5
0000002BC: 94 F4
000000320: 94 F3
000000384: 94 F2
000001000: 94 F1
000001064: 94 20
```

Comment: All answers were useful, but this solution is by far the most efficient. Thank you very much. That really helped me, you learned me new things.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to split the string into line using `str.splitlines()` or `.split('\n')` and then strip out the characters that you dont want.

```
x = "\n".join([line.strip("->").strip(",") for line in decShow.splitlines()])
```

Answer (score 0):

`for line in decShow` treats `decShow` as a list of characters. You want to have a list of all the lines in `decShow` which is easily reachable using `decShow.split("\n")`, and then `for line in decShow.split("\n")` will give each `line` the value of a single line in `decShow`.

Comment: (str.splitlines)[https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines] will be more robust here.

Answer (score 0):

If `decShow` is a `str`, then your `for` loop will loop over characters, not lines.  In order to loop over lines separated by [newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) characters, try using [str.splitlines](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines):

```
for line in decShow.splitlines():
    // convert line to your Hex representation here
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `decShow.split("\n")` and it will split the string into multiple strings by the new line character. You can also use the same thing for example if you wanted to split that first part by commas `decShow.split(",")`

In addition, I think for this problem you're also going to need to do some substrings depending on how you go about it. You can read more about that elsewhere...

[How to display the first few characters of a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714859/how-to-display-the-first-few-characters-of-a-string-in-python)