# How can I display text in pyramid shape in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to display any string in pyramid shape e.g. if I am to enter 'adil', I want to display it like

```
a
ad
adi
adil
```

```
inp = input('Enter something: ')
l = len(inp)

i=0
while i < l:
    for j in range(l):
        print(inp[j])
        i+=1
```

Comment: Don't use `while i < l` **and** `for j in range(l)`. Just `for j in range(l)` is enough.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display the first few characters of a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714859/how-to-display-the-first-few-characters-of-a-string-in-python)

Comment: I have tried it but its showing all characters vertically.

Comment: Yes. `inp[j]` is a single character. If you print single characters in a loop they will be displayed vertically. Use string slices instead (see the question I have linked).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative, this will print it like a pyramid (triangle):

```
inp = "adil"

for i, l in enumerate(inp):
    print(inp[:i+1].center(len(inp)))
```

Output:

```
 a  
 ad 
adi 
adil
```

Or, remove `center` to print like the example in your question:

```
inp = "adil"

for i, l in enumerate(inp):
    print(inp[:i+1])
```

Comment: spot on. Exactly what I was looking for. huge thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use slicing and format strings:

```
fmt='{:^'+str(len(s)+1)+'s}' # format strings centers text 
for i in range(1,len(s)+1): print(fmt.format(s[:i]))
```

Works (optically) better with longer strings